# How does Java.math.BigInteger.and() work?

Tags: java, biginteger

According to [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_and.htm) the result from Java.math.BigInteger.and() when calling .and() with values 6 and 3 is 2. How does this work? It's neither concatenating nor adding.

Comment: Note that, while Java's BigInteger doesn't actually store in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), the results of and-ing two negative BigIntegers or one positive and one negative BigInteger are **as if** they are two's complement. For positive BigIntegers, there is no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Logical bitwise And operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

`6 = 110b`  (b means binary)
`3 = 011b`

`110b & 011b = 010b = 2`

Answer (score 1):

AND Truth table is following for 2 inputs

[image]

so for two integers 3 and 4

```
3 = 011b
4 = 100b
```

b means in base 2.

The and operation of `3&4 = 011&100.`

so applying AND truth table for each bit position we get

```
1&0 = 0

1&0 = 0

0&1 = 1
```

Actually, I am applying and operation LSB to MSB for both numbers.

Now `Biginteger class` is introduced for calculating the large number which does not fit primitive data types `long  int`.

`BigInteger` will do the same operation but for too big numbers.

Comment: If you do it bitwise, you get `1&0 = 0, 1&0 = 0, 0&1 = 0`, meaning `3&4 = 0`. But `6&3 = 2`, because `1&0 = 0, 1&1 = 1, 0&1 = 0`, so you get 2.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis g8 moderation

Answer (score 0):

Its bitwise And operation.In your question given link shows,

```
110 & 011 = 010
110 is the binary value of 6.
011 is the binary value of 3.
```

The result `010` is the binary of `2(decimal)`.

Answer (score 0):

It does the & (Bitwise And). Which means it returns the matching 1's in its binary representation.
For example, 6 is 0110, 3 is 0011 so:
6 & 3 is 0110 & 0011 = 0010 = 2

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger in java is same like primitive types int and long.All Bitwise operations that you are doing on numeric primitive types is same as and(),or(),xor() methods of BigInteger.BigInteger is like  unlimited integer there is no fixed memory for it
(for example int is 4 bytes  Minimum value is - 2,147,483,648.(-2^31) Maximum value is 2,147,483,647(inclusive).(2^31 -1)).Your BigInteger is internally stored as

final int[] mag;

For and() method
If your BigInteger value is more than int type it will add to array.Bitwise operations are done between array of interger on both inputs for example you have two bigintegers x and y

It will calculate like
x.mag[0] & y.mag[0]
x.mag[1] & y.mag[1]
.
.
Add those all values returned by each and sum it up and give you final value.Finally its same like Bitwise operations &,|;

Comment: See my other comment. Java's BigIntegers are not stored as two's complement, they are stored in sign-magnitude format (and, weirdly enough, top limb first, but not really big-endian). To do bitwise operations, the results are **as if** they are two's complement, though. That means that, as soon one or both operands are negative, you can't simply `and` the magnitude values.